# How to access the elements in <script> inside the body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `<script>` inside the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $('#audioVolume').text($('#audioVolume').text(Math.round((document.mediaPlayer.Volume + 2000) / 10) + "%"));
</script>
```

Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object.

Need: I want to access the html elements in `<script` inside the body tag.

Comment: Break the code down. Figure out which construct is turning out undefined. Make sure that it really does exist.

Comment: I would guess that mediaPlayer is your problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best guess - `document.mediaPlayer` is undefined.  I think you've also got a typo - you're setting the text of the element to the result of setting the text of the element?  Try wrapping the whole thing inside a ready function so that it doesn't run until the DOM is loaded.  If that doesn't work, then fire up the debugger tools in IE8 and see which element isn't defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(function() {
     $('#audioVolume').text(Math.round((document.mediaPlayer.Volume + 2000) / 10) + "%"));
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#audioVolume').text(Math.round((document.mediaPlayer.Volume + 2000) / 10) + "%");
});
</script>
```